# Partitioning in SAP HANA

Tags: partitioning, hana

We are new to SAP HANA DB. We have newly formed application with 25-30 tables.

Maximum records in tables are around one million. Data is maintained date wise.

Should we go for Daywise partition? We know that volume is less. We only maintain data for particular period so after some time it will be easy to drop partition.

Daily growth of these tables is around 5K(max). IS it ok to go for partition in columnar database or currently there is no need for partition?

Will deletion of record give same performance as drop partition?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

With max 1 million records per table there is typically no need at all for partitioning in SAP HANA! I have never experienced any performance problems whatsoever with such small tables. In theory there could be a positive performance impact when you partition daywise and select the data daywise. On the other hand this can lead to many partitions, which can have a negative impact. Also the difference in performance between "delete" and "drop partition" is not relevant given the size of your data.

My recommendation: start with plain column tables, measure performance of your queries, only if you observe problems start thinking about optimization.